# Можно ли переписать этот метод через Stream API?

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

Как переписать этот метод через Stream API? Тут получается for each в for each , как считать просто коллекцию через стрим я понимаю, а касательно таких вариаций не попалось ни 1 примера, такое практикуется ?

```
public void getCurrency(String currency) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Main p = new Main();

    for (Params elem : p.parseJson().getOrgs()) {
        for (Securities elem1: elem.getSecurities()) {
            if(currency.equals(elem1.getCurrency()))
                //System.out.println("Название " + elem1.name + " Код " + elem1.code + " " + elem1.currency);
                System.out.println("В валюте " + currency + " торгуются бумаги " + elem1.getName()
                        + " Код " + elem1.getCode() + " " + elem1.getCurrency() + " id "
                + elem1.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно конечно какие проблемы?

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем вот так получилось переписать у меня этот цикл, может кому пригодится

```
p.parseJson().stream()
            .map(elem -> {
                return elem.getSecurities();
            })
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .forEach(elem -> {
                    if(currency.equals(elem.getCurrency()))
                        //System.out.println("Название " + elem1.name + " Код " + elem1.code + " " + elem1.currency);
                        System.out.println("В валюте " + currency + " торгуются бумаги " + elem.getName()
                                + " Код " + elem.getCode() + " " + elem.getCurrency() + " id "
                                + elem.getId());
            });
```

Comment: Ну за неимением всего кода я лиш показал пример

Comment: Всё равно спасибо за ответ,  я уже сделал вывод, что лучше публиковать все связанные классы и методы с вопросом в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 0):

Так думаю если ваши getOrgs и getSecurities это списки

```
p.parseJson().getOrgs().stream().forEach( elem -> {
      elem.getSecurities().stream().forEach( elem1-> {
            if(currency.equals(elem1.getCurrency()))
                //System.out.println("Название " + elem1.name + " Код " + elem1.code + " " + elem1.currency);
                System.out.println("В валюте " + currency + " торгуются бумаги " + elem1.getName()
                        + " Код " + elem1.getCode() + " " + elem1.getCurrency() + " id "
                + elem1.getId());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Orgs и Securities это классы
Они нужны так как парсил файл с помощью gson

Странно код не робит, подчеркивает красным все поля где есть get в названии
Попробовал слегка изменить код, первую строчку вот так
p.parseJson().stream().forEach( elem -> {

после этого поля с get подчеркивать перестал, но ругается на скобки